# Querying many to many relationships

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, many-to-many

I saw the post on relationships on the official asp.net core documentation:
[asp.net core model relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string TagId { get; set; }

    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class PostTag
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

If I wanted to return a list of all the Tags, I would do this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Tag>> AllTags()
{
return await _context.Tags
.Include(q => q.PostTags).ThenInclude(q => q.Post);
}
```

How can I return the Tags and number of posts they applied to?

Example =

> Budget (3)

Comment: What is `_context`?

Comment: ApplicationDbContext _context; I'm assuming the readers know I'm trying to create a repository pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a view model class to represent the data you want to pass

```
public class PostCount
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your action method, you can query the `Tags` collection and and call the  `Count` method on the `PostTags` property of each `Tag` object. In your LINQ expression, you can do a projection to create your view model object.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<PostCount>> AllTags()
{
    var tags = await _context.Tags
                             .Select(a => new PostCount
                                          {
                                             Name = a.Name,
                                             Count = a.PostTags.Count()
                                          }
                                    ).ToListAsync();

    return tags;
}
```

The above will return the data you want when you access this action method.

If you are showing this in a view, you can return the list we created to your view. in your view, which is strongly typed to a list of `PostCount` class, you can render the tag name and it's post count

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<PostCount>> AllTags()
{
    var tags = await _context.Tags.Select(a => new PostCount
    {
        Name = a.Name,
        Count = a.PostTags.Count()
    }).ToListAsync();

    return View(tags);
}
```

and in your `AllTags.cshtml` view,

```
@model List<PostCount>
<h3>Tags</h3>
@foreach(var tag in Model)
{
  <p>@tag.Name  @tag.Count </p>
}
```

Also you probably need to have a primary key property in your `PostTag` class

```
public class PostTag
{
   public int Id  { set;get; }
   // other properties you have
}
```